# Swift 3 error: Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Tags: swift

So I know this question has been asked and answered numerous times before, but I just migrated my project to Swift 3 and Im getting a ton of these errors in my code that parses JSON and I couldn't quite find answers that made me understand how to resolve my specific issue.

```
guard let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject] else {
        return
    }
    guard let responseData = result["Data"] else { return }
    guard let userData = responseData["UserProfile"] else { return }

    var userProfileFieldsDict = [String: String]()

    if let sessionToken = userData!["CurrentSessionToken"] as? NSString {
        userProfileFieldsDict["sessionToken"] = String(sessionToken)

    }
}
```

The `if let sessionToken` line throws the aforementioned error, but not quite sure how you're supposed to deal with this in Swift 3? Could someone explain and suggest a best practice fix?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `responseData["UserProfile"]` is also a dictionary you'll probably want to cast it as such in you guard by saying `guard let userData = responseData["UserProfile"] as? [String : AnyObject] else { return }`.  I suspect this will solve your problem.

As a small aside, you don't need to force unwrap userData in your if let, because you've already unwrapped it in the guard.

Comment: Hmm, cool. But how and why has this behavior changed since Swift 2?

Comment: Honestly, this should have always been a problem - if you don't cast responseData["UserProfile"] all the compiler knows is that it's AnyObject, which you can't subscript.  I can't say for sure without running the code myself.

Comment: Ultimately Swift wants you to be really explicit about types of objects, so it's definitely best practice to check the type in your guard statement the way I described unless you're using generics or something.  It's a little more typing, but worth it to avoid these kinds of bugs.

Comment: Thanks, I completely agree with your argument, though puzzling that Swift 2 didn't react to this. Cheers!

Comment: I'm not sure if this has any bearing, but in Swift2, many types were automatically made `AnyObject` whereas in Swift3 many of those were changed from `AnyObject` to `Any`. I've dealt with a number of cases worked in Swift2 because something was an AnyObject which is more specific and accommodating than an Any. Without digging into your specific error in more detail, I can say that it smells similar, given the regression from Swift2 to Swift3